# Is there a way to Obfuscate or Mask values in a Data Frame column?

Tags: python, pandas, jupyter-notebook, plotly, data-analysis

I'm trying to mask all the IPs in a DataFrame column. I have a DataFrame with columns that contain IP addresses. For privacy and security reasons, I need to hide\mask the first 2 octets when the  DataFrame is displayed as a table or graphed with Plotly. What approach do you think would be best? The only way I can think to do it is to make an additional column and use the apply function to process the IP into a X.X.1.1 format.

Comment: `df['masked_IP'] = df.IP.str.replace('^[^.]+\.[^.]+', 'x.x')`

Answer (score 0):

Your approch doesn't seem wrong. You could also duplicate the dataset and encrypt the copy ( in case you want to save the new dataset ) .

Or if you just want to preserve the privacy you could use anonymization techniques. It will help you in bigger projects when you want to preserve confidentiality, here are some links

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Data_anonymization
https://iapp.org/resources/article/guide-to-basic-data-anonymization-techniques/

Answer (score 0):

```
import pandas as pd
from pandas.compat import StringIO

print(pd.__version__)

csvdata = StringIO("""IP
192.168.1.10
192.168.1.11
192.168.1.12
192.168.1.13""")

df = pd.read_csv(csvdata)
df['IP'] = df['IP'].apply(lambda x: "X.X."+".".join(x.split('.')[2:4]))
print(df)
```

Will produce

```
0.24.2
         IP
0  X.X.1.10
1  X.X.1.11
2  X.X.1.12
3  X.X.1.13
```

And is probably the best way to 'redact' data in a `DataFrame`